# Mongoose Promises query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm creating a reservation system of sorts using mongoose and nodejs. There are a list of hotels which have number of available rooms as a field. While creating a new booking for a customer, I want to check if the number of available rooms in the particular hotel greater than 0 and if it is, update the number of available rooms in the hotel by reducing it by 1.

Here is my code

-Hotel Model file

```
var hotel: new mongoose.Schema{
name: String, 
availableRooms: {type: Number, default: 1}}
```

-Booking Model file

```
var booking: new mongoose.Schema{
userName: String,
hotelId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'hotel'}
}
```

Here's the functionality for booking a room.

```
Hotel.findOneAndUpdate(
{ '_id': hotelId, 'availableRooms': { '$gt': 0 } },
{ '$inc': { 'availableRooms': -1 } }, 
function (err, hotel) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else if (hotel && hotel.availableRooms > 0) {
        booking.create(req.body, function(err, confirmedBooking){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(confirmedBooking);
        });
    }
}
);
```

Could this code be done more efficiently using Mongoose Promises? If so, what would the code look like?